# How Multi-party Computation works

Tags: multiparty-computation

I'm new to MPC. I was reading about it when I found an example that seemed to be trivial about how it works.

In the picture below, the way X1 sends its data to X2 is by generating a huge random number, add its number to it, and send this to X2. X2 will do the same by adding its value to what it has received, and then send that to X3, and so on.

This does not look secure to me. Isn't the direct addition trivial?

[image: The example I found]

Comment: Here, the word "trivial" may confuse some readers. "Trivial" commonly means "of little worth or importance", but in mathematics it can mean "relating to or being the mathematically simplest case".

Comment: Welcome to MPC world where there are honest, semi-honest, malicious, covert, adversaries, etc. The first question is what is the context here? what is the source of this picture? If everyone is at least semi-honest it will work. Why it is not secure to you? are you malicious in this MPC?

Comment: I was discussing this with someone today. zHe told me that the addition should be modular in order for this to be secure. And I didn't understand how this works. I took a screenshot for this, and I unfortunately don't remember the source. It was for a presentation for a paper on MPC.